# Unlock My Phone! January 2018

Tags: knowledge, visual

I can't remember my phone's password! Ever since January of 2018 I have changed my phone's password every month to stay secure, however even I have trouble remembering my passwords. Luckily my background gives me a clue as to what it is. Some of these clues are easy to solve and some are difficult.

**What is my phone's password this month?**

[image]

Hint:

> My passwords are usually pretty long (sometimes as long as 30 digits).

Comment: Who else has seen this particular spiral? ;)

Comment: It is golden ratio spiral

Comment: Plot twist: OP is actually hacking someone else's phone, and now we're accomplices!

Comment: No, I'm not hacking anybody's phone. I (sadly enough) don't know anybody with cool puzzles on their phones!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @LeppyR64's answer and the new hint, could the password be

> 161803398874989484820458683437

This is

> $\phi \times 10^{30}$, rounded (since the numbers after the decimal point would be 6.56 rounded to 7).

Comment: You got it! Nice job. On to the next month!

Comment: [Next month's puzzle.](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81316/unlock-my-phone-february-2018)

Answer (score 3):

Is the password:

> PHIe30

Notes:

> Phi is the golden ratio, as symbolized with the symbol and the drawing.  phi x 10^30 is phi e 30.

Comment: Even if this doesn't turn out to be correct, I think it's pretty dang smart! +1

Comment: It's very, very close! You're on the right track, but I'll add a hint to my post that will help a bit.